# SSH Expect skipping "more" prompt on router

Tags: ssh, expect, router, net-ssh

after testing several modules for sending SSH commands with PERL, my choice is for the **Net::SSH::Expect** module (able to send mutiple commands for a unique connection)

I am still testing some functions on it, here's my code :

```
use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $user="myuser";
my $host = "126.30.186.249";
my $passwd = "mypasswd";


my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(host => "$host", password=> "$passwd", user => "$user", raw_pty => 1 );
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
$ssh->send("sh arp");
my $line ;
while ( defined ($line = $ssh->read_line()) ) {
    print $line . "\n" ;
}
```

Here's my issue : When using the "**exec**" function instead of "**send**" :

```
sh arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  126.30.186.3          112   0080.9f8b.fc1a  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.186
Internet  126.30.186.6          163   0080.9f8b.fc1a  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.186
Internet  126.30.186.247          -   e4c7.2291.5181  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.186
Internet  126.30.186.248         33   885a.9291.c7e1  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.186
Internet  126.30.186.249          -   0000.0c07.ac65  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.186
Internet  126.30.186.250          -   0000.0c07.ac66  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.186
Internet  126.30.187.241         38   0017.e05d.b144  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.230
Internet  126.30.187.242         96   0012.dada.65c1  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.230
Internet  126.30.187.243         96   f025.7275.63c1  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.230
Internet  126.30.187.250          -   0000.0c07.ac00  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.230
Internet  126.30.187.251          -   e4c7.2291.5181  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1.230
 **--More--**
```

This "**MORE**" prompt is a problem.
So as you can see, i tried with "**send**" and made a while loop. The result given is the same, but without the --More-- prompt. 
I need to skip the **"more"** prompt and see all the result. 
Net::OpenSSH is giving me all the result when sending a "capture".
I searched for any functions skipping automatically the "more" prompt... But not results :(
Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks.

Comment: A friend told me to use the command "term le 0" on router before sending other commands.
But i can't make it work with other commands. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the `**--More-**` prompts from the output?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
my $out2 = $ssh->exec ("term le 0");
```

before executing any command is working. That allows the terminal emulated by the SSH connection to not limit the line buffer
Working on Cisco/Hp materials. I don't know if it's working on any other.